# My broadcast receiver can't get BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast

Tags: android

I install and open it , and reboot my phone , but my receiver did't receive broadcast to start my service and without log.

My phone is Asus LF2 .

How can I start my service in device boot completed?

My Receiver

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    public BootReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG , "Deyu onReceive " + intent.getAction());
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AlarmMessageService.class));
    }
}
```

My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="go.deyu.dailytodo"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".AlarmMessageService"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This code in Samsung's phone is work ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find why my app in my phone can't get boot complete broadcast.

There is a Auto-start Manager setting in my Asus Phone.

When I allow my app to Auto-start , my App work fine....

[image: Ausu LF2 Auto-start Manager]

Comment: You just save my day!

Comment: How to do this programmatically? As after installing from Play Store we cannot force the user to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` from the `<receiver>` element.

Comment: I just tried, but still have not received broadcast.

Comment: @Deyu瑜: Have you run the activity since installing/upgrading the app?

Comment: Yeah , I have run after installing .

Comment: @Deyu瑜: See if there is anything in LogCat, such as not being able to find your receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<receiver
       android:name=".receivers.RestartReceiver"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.1 or above,if you want to deal with `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcastreceiver.You must pay attention to this:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

1.Make sure you have turned on your app after you installed.I think you did it.

2.Check your android mobile device settings: Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Force Stop.If the Force Stop is turned on,please turn off it.

3.Another point you should check is `android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver"`,be careful of the path,maybe system can not find your BootReceiver.